# Symfony 2.7: ¿Como desplegar o pasar a producción mi aplicación?

Tags: symfony2, deployment

Quiero poner en **estado de producción** mi aplicación realizada en **Symfony 2.7**, pero no encuentro información detallada sobre el proceso que se debe llevar a cabo.
Preguntas:

- ¿que configuraciones dentro de `app/` debo cambiar?
- ¿que configuraciones dentro de `web/` debo cambiar?
- en general, ¿que archivos de configuración debo editar, que exactamente debo cambiar?
- ¿que comandos debo ejecutar para realizar este proceso?

Answer (score 1):

¿A que te refieres con "poner la app en estado de producción"?. Si te refieres a hostearla en un servidor y accederla mediante el entorno de producción, no tienes que cambiar nada en los ficheros de configuración, lo único que tienes que hacer es subir el proyecto para el servidor y accederla poniendo al final del dominio "app.php". O sea, en la url que escribes en el navegador reemplazas "app_dev.php" por "app.php" y ya estarás viendo la aplicación en el entorno de producción.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sube tu código fuente al servidor.
2. Instala las dependencias de tu proyecto (Normalmente, esto se realiza con vía composer, con el comando `composer install`
3. Ejecuta los procesos de migración de base de datos o similares.
4. Limpia la caché (console cache:clear) Opcionalmente también puedes ejecutar el comando para realizar un cache warmup y evitar tiempos de carga excesivos la primera vez que se genera la caché para tu aplicación en un entorno de producción.

Estos son los pasos básicos. Si tu máquina está bien configurada, no necesitas hacer ningún cambio en los ficheros del framework.

Aquí tienes más información sobre este tema, en inglés: [How to deploy a symfony application](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/deployment/tools.html)

En ese enlace podrás consultar herramientas para hacer dicho deploy, que te ayudarán y reducirán drásticamente los tiempos y los errores al hacer deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Para deploys de symfony yo uso capifony (http://capifony.org/), pero eso si, a partir de symfony3 da problemas (aquí deberias usar capistrano, ansible, etc etc)

También puedes currarte un CI (coninuous integration) con Jenkins o Travis, que te lo puedes configurar para que se te baje el código, por ejemplo de github, luego tira todos los test y si está todo OK, te hace el deploy.